# Spotting the difference between an n! and a 2^n algorithm

Tags: algorithm, big-o, time-complexity

I've seen a few interesting discussions recently debating whether or not a given ("hard") problem has at-best an 2^n or n! known solution.

My question is, aside from actually walking through the algorithm and seeing the growth rate, is there a heuristic for quickly spotting one versus the other?  Ie. are there certain quickly-observable properties of an algorithm that make it obviously one or the other?

Related discussions:

- https://stackoverflow.com/a/5508483/26624
- http://news.ycombinator.com/item?id=3621555

Comment: big-O notation says about the running time of an algorithm.. and in your first sentence you have mentioned about n^2 or n! known solution... Can you modify the question.. I find it a little confusing...

Comment: By "known solution" I'm referring to the algorithm that solves the problem.  Sorry... I think it's clear but I'm happy to reword it if you have a suggestion.

Comment: Hhhmm I get it now.. Thought it must have been running time... never mind. Amit has the answer..

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is no algorithm that can determine a complexity of a program [at all]. It is a part of the [Halting Problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Halting_problem) - you cannot determine if a certain algorithm will stop or not. [You cannot estimate if it is `Theta(infinity)` or anything less then it]

As a rule of thumb - **usually** `O(n!)` algorithms are invoking recursive call in a loop with a decreasing range, while `O(2^n)` algorithms invoke a recursive call twice in each call.

**Note**: Not all algorithms that invokes a recursive call twice are `O(2^n)` - a quicksort is a good example for an `O(nlogn)` algorithm which also invokes a recursive call twice.

**EDIT: For example:** 

[SAT](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SAT) brute-force solution `O(2^n)`:

```
SAT(formula,vars,i):
  if i == vars.length:
      return formula.isSatisfied(vars)
  vars[i] = true
  temp = SAT(formula,vars,i+1)  //first recursive call
  if (temp == true) return true
  vars[i] = false
  return SAT(formula,vars,i+1)  //second recursive call
```

Find all permutations: `O(n!)`

```
permutations(source,sol):
  if (source.length == 0): 
      print sol
      return
  for each e in source: 
      sol.append(e)
      source.remove(e)
      permutations(source,sol) //recursive call in a loop
      source.add(e)
      sol.removeLast()
```

Comment: This is an incorrect interpretation of the Halting Problem. It is impossible to write a program that, when given _any_ other program and _any_ input to it, can determine whether the program will halt on that input, _and which will always work, whichever program+input you feed it with_. It is, however, fully possible to write a program that, for _many_ programs and inputs, will be able to determine whether it will halt, but will fail to determine this for other programs.

Comment: @AasmundEldhuset: actually, the problem is not even in [RE](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RE_%28complexity%29). There is a reduction from the Not_Halting_Problem. Given `(M,x)`: create `M'` that on input `w` runs 2^|w| steps on M with input x. If M doesn't halt - M' stops. Else: It continue to run |w|! steps. It is easy to prove that (M,x) doesn't halt if and only if M' is `O(2^n)`

Comment: My point was just that your formulation (as I read it) makes it sound like "given any program, it is impossible to programmatically determine the complexity of that particular program", rather than "it is impossible to write a program that can determine the complexity of any possible program". My apologies for the somewhat crass opening, by the way.

Answer (score 1):

As amit mentioned it is theoretically not possible to check if an algorithm is O(2^n) or O(n!). However you can use the following heuristics:

1. For different values of n calculate the number of steps, F(n), to solve
2. Plot  n vs log( F(n) )/n
3. If it looks like a flat line (or levels off as a flat line) then it is O(2^n)
4. If it looks like a strictly increasing function, then is is super exponential
5. If it looks more line a x vs log(x) plot, then it is "probably" O(n!)